# If $E_1+E_2$ is a projection then $E_1E_2=E_2E_1=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm attempting to show that if $E_1+E_2$ is a projection (where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are also projections) then $E_1E_2=E_2E_1=0.$ In an earlier problem I showed that $E_1+E_2$ is a projection if and only if $E_1E_2+E_2E_1=0$, I'm not sure if this helps here though.

I'm also told to consider $E_1E_2E_1$ in two different ways, I'm not sure how to go about this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already shown that $EF +FE = 0$ iff $F+E$ is a projection.
By multiplying both sides from the left and the right by $F$, we have, as $F^2=F$, \begin{align}2 FEF = FEF + FEF = 0\end{align} and thus $FEF =0$.
On the other hand, by multipying both sides from the right with $1 - F$ we have as $F(1-F) =0$
\begin{align*}
FE = FE - FEF =EF(1-F)+ FE(1-F)=0
\end{align*}
which proves the claim.
As a note, the converse, $EF =0$ implies $F+E$ is a projection, is also true.